# Quick-sort computational cost calculation

Tags: sorting

If a list of number is given in descending order. What will be the computational cost to arrange it in ascending order by quick sort

Comment: There exist different variants of quicksort.

Comment: @PeterG. If we consider 2-partition and 3-partition quicksort..

Comment: no previous attempts? http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Quick sort, if the first element is chosen as the pivot element for partitioning..then 
Quick sort exhibits its worst cast complexity - O(n^2) in this case. 
More precisely, Quick sort's worst case complexity of O(n^2) is observed when the input to be sorted is in decreasing order or increasing order (if the first elemnet is the pivot element).

The reason for this worst case performance is that, after partitioning , one partition will be of size 1 , and the other will be of size n-1 
So, the Time to quick sort 'n' elements T(n) = 
 
Time it takes to partition 'n' elements O(n) + Time to quick sort 'n-1' elements T(n-1) 
So, T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n) 
=>  T(n) = O(n^2)

Please dont forget to accept the answer. Feel free to ask anything, which you are unclear about